# Custom multiline edit for QuoteLineItems and population of description field

Tags: apex, custom-field, quote, quotelineitem

I need to edit the multiple page layout of the QuoteLineItem object.
I'm able to show a custom field, however I need to populate that field with a value from the pricebook2 associated to the product.

Is it possible to create a totally custom multi-line page? otherwise can I inject custom logic through apex or javascript?

Comment: Depending on what exact field from pricebook2 you want to access and wether you want only to view or also want to edit it, there are several approches. You should be more specific about your requiremens.

Comment: I only need to retrieve the description of the pricebook2 object. I only need to copy the PriceBook2's description in a custom field inside the new QuoteLineItem.

Comment: Actually there is no standard description field on pricebookentry, its on product. If readonly is good enough, you go with a formula. If you want to get that description a template an be able to edit it independant from its value at product, you will need an trigger on qoute line item.

Comment: Excuse me, I explained me badly! I need to copy the Pricebook's description in the new QuoteLineItem, then the user can edit this description in QuoteLineItem. Obviously the PriceBook's description won't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you want to create a custom edit table for all lineItems on a quote which contains fileds from pricebook2. This can be done with a visualforce page and an apex controller. Here you find a generic example which you need to adjust to your scenario.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_custom_list_controller.htm

You can create a custom button on the quote view page, which routes you to your new line item edit page. There you edit the line items, save them and return back to the qoute view.

So far no need of javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you provide me the link to the generic example you have quoted? :)

Comment: Added the link, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display a description read-only you can use a custom formula field on quote line item. Add a new custom field, choose type formula, give it a name, and enter this as a value

PricebookEntry.Product2.Description

this you can use like all other fields of the line item on the standard layout but you cant change it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you create an before insert trigger on QuoteLineItem where you copy the content of pricebookentry.product2.description to your custom field. Than you can stick with the standard ui and need no custom vf-page. But sooner or later you will probably create your custom page because the standard is not very nice.